# Alt + Enter wont open suggestions when pressed on empty spaces

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I was using quick assist in **Eclipse** to quickly generate constructors when pointing on an empty space 1 line below a class declaration, after migrating to **Android Studio** i was hoping i could do the same.

Unfortunately on my **Android Studio** pressing `Alt+Enter` while cursor pointing at the first line after class declaration :

[image]

doesnt do anything! and i have to right click that postion and generate the ctor the hard and long way or write it by myself, is the quick assist not openning a bug or is it the way it is suppose to be?

if its a bug how can i fix it? if its not, what is the quickest way to generate a ctor?

Comment: on my android studio it's `ctrl+return`

Answer (score 2):

i Believe you are looking for `Alt+Insert`.